# SpecFlow throws error looking for assembly, but it's not my SpecFlow project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, specflow

Have started using SpecFlow recently for API acceptance tests, all is well on first try, but then I get the error below on consequent builds. Deleting the obj and bin folder from my API project and a rebuild fixes it, but then a build after, and it's back.

Please remember this isn't my SpecFlow tests project, it's the project that is being tested, so really shouldn't have any SpecFlow assemblies referenced?

Any ideas what I need to do to make this work without deleting the obj and bin folders time and time again?

The error I get when trying to load any controller action is:
[image: SpecFlow Error]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is after a build the TechTalk.SpecFlow.dll in your bin folder?

If not check following:

- it is set to CopyLocal=true in the References
- Before/After Build events
- custom MSBuild stuff in the *.csproj that removes files

And yes, the project that is tested should not contain a reference to Specflow. Are they using some Utils from it? When they have the bindings in this project, they should move them to a separate assembly.

Comment: It's not a reference in the actual API project. Only in the Test Project, so yes it's in a separate assembly. There's no utils from the test project in the API project.

Comment: @JamesWoodley Are there somehow references to the Test project from the api project or an other project that is referenced by the api project? 
Can you look into the fusion logs for the SpecFlow assembly what is loading the dll?
Did you check the build stuff?

Comment: So strangely I think it was a Visual Studio extension problem. I've run all the updates (one being a Visual Studio update itself) and now it seems to have stopped happening!

Answer (score 0):

Updating all the Visual Studio Tools and Extensions seemed to have resolved this issue. Maybe there was a problem with the SpecFlow extension and upgrading Visual Studio 2015 to the newer Update (Service Pack?) seems to have stopped this reference error!

Thanks to Andreas for taking the time to help me out!